# Next js won't compile scss when i try to user mixins in my project

Tags: next.js, sass

I am now using nextjs 13.
Here is my project structure

```
src
   app
      global.scss
      mixins.scss
      palette.scss
   components
      ComponentA.tsx
      componentA.module.scss
```

What i trying to do is in the `componentA.module.scss` i am trying to import `mixins.scss`

Initially there are no `mixins` file. only `palette` which declare some color variables.

in the `componentA.module.scss` i can import `palette` using `@import "../../../app/palette.scss";`
it doesn't give me any error.

But when I try to import `mixins` using `@import` it won't work. I also try using `@use` it won't work either

Comment: prefix all scss files with `_filename.scss` except the main sass file.